# how i can reduce the digits after the decimal point?

Tags: vb.net, point, downcast

I need only up to two decimal points.

Dim v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, tv, rp1, rp2, rp3, rp4, rp5 As Double

Dim Per1, Per2, Per3, Per4, per5 As Double

```
    Per1 = v1 / tv * 100

    Per2 = v2 / tv * 100

    Per3 = v3 / tv * 100

    Per4 = v4 / tv * 100

    per5 = v5 / tv * 100
```

It gives me values like per1=76.34393939202

But if I use :
 Dim Per1, Per2, Per3, Per4, per5 As ULong
It gives me 76

I want that it to gives me values like 76.34 but how i can do it? Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

If you convert a Double to ULong it will remove all decimal places. If the problem is when you print them to screen, then you can simply use a string formatter:

```
Format(Per1, "0.00")
```

Documentation can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.format.aspx

If you want to round the numbers you can use

```
Math.Round(Per1, 2)
```

Round is documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

in c# it looks like this

```
 string.Format("{0:0.00}", (double)Convert.ToInt32(tv) * 100 / Convert.ToInt32(v1))
```